# Why my files that Encrypted with EFS in Windows 8.1 shown in Linux ubuntu?

Tags: encryption, linux, disk-encryption, file-encryption, logging

i Encrypted my files with EFS in windows 8.1

so

i logged in ubuntu and without any warning , its shown my files

actually not Exactly the file

but shown the path of file and the name

and i can enter to the folder that Encrypted with EFS , In other words the green folder , I can get into the green folder.

but i do not have access to files

how can I prevent from entering the folder, the green folder(that encrypted with efs) with another os???like ubuntu???

thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is normal. It's how EFS works.

> Although it is common to refer to file folders with the encryption attribute set as “encrypted,” the folder itself is not encrypted. When encryption is set for a folder, EFS automatically encrypts all new files created in the folder and all files copied or moved into the folder by using My Computer.

(Source: Microsoft TechNet: [Using Encrypting File System](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457116)) (Archived [here](https://archive.today/lkebW).)

You may want to use full disk encryption like [TrueCrpyt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt) or Microsoft's own [BitLocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) instead of EFS.

**EFS ZIPs**
Edit: EFS-encrypted ZIP files are a quick and dirty workaround.

> File names in encrypted folder are not protected. Actually, encrypting folder contents means automatically applying encryption to all files in the folder, not encrypting directory data itself.
>
> Since the file name itself could contain sensitive information, it could be a breach in security. One of the solutions would be using encrypted .zip archives instead of folders, which are treated by Windows XP almost like folders. Thus, only one file is needed to be encrypted and archived data themselves are harder to crack.

(Source: NTFS.com: [EFS - Encrypting File System. Encrypted Files and Folders
(NTFS v. 3.0 and newer)](http://ntfs.com/issues-encrypted-files.htm) (Archived [here](https://archive.today/KtSuw).))

Comment: Truecrypt is considered insecure, according to the developers. They discontinued the project and warned against its use. There are some forks from Truecrypt that may or may not be secure.

Comment: Yep. But the last non crippled version of TrueCrypt seems good. Passed its audit okay.  See http://istruecryptauditedyet.com